# --add-host failed within play application docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I'm fairly new to docker and containers, and what I have is a play application docker image which I built from Windows like this:

```
activator docker:publishLocal
```

I took this image and ran it on linux successfully. But, when I try to run a command like:

```
docker run -it --add-host db-static:86.75.30.9 greedy/myserver cat /etc/hosts
```

I get:

```
Bad root server path: /opt/docker/cat
```

I'm basically trying to add an entry to the hosts file. 
Although I followed the docs, it seems a bit confusing to me, because I can only add entries into images, and not running containers this way.

Any one knows how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty difficult to guess what's wrong with your image, could be that bash shell is missing and cat command was not executed. --add-host will allow you to add the entry to the container but since containers are transient, you will have to pass it at startup every time you run the container. It would not be bad idea to add the mapping at the time docker build.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your image has an `ENTRYPOINT` defined, you need to [override](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime) it:

```
docker run -it --add-host db-static:86.75.30.9 --entrypoint /bin/bash greedy/myserver cat /etc/hosts
```